# plot() in R doesn't give scatter plot

Tags: r, plot

I was expecting points but got this when I did

```
plot(data$v3,data$v2)
```

[image: the graph I got from plot()]

my data

```
    V2   V3
2  -2.0  2.7
3   0.5  3.9
4   1.3  4.5
5   5.7  6.0
6  10.4  8.7
7   3.4  2.7
8   7.6  3.2
9   4.1  5.6
10  5.0  9.2
11  8.5 11.7
12 12.3  6.8
13 16.1 13.0
14 13.2 11.9
15  8.8  8.6
16  7.9  6.1
17  1.1  4.9
18  3.0  1.0
19  4.5  7.2
20  2.7  2.7
21  7.6  7.6
```

I tried searching but from my understanding the function is supposed to give points, not bars. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your data is not numeric. Check `str(data)`.

Comment: you were right. thank you very much